# Como criar novos campos no banco de dados do Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, wordpress

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema estilo Infojobs, Catho e CEVIU em Wordpress, baseado em um Theme já criado para este fim. Para um usuário realizar o cadastro no site, por padrão do tema, ele tem que fornecer os seguintes dados: e-mail, senha, confirmação de senha e selecionar em um campo select se ele é uma empresa ou candidato.

Estou precisando implementar mais um campo, CPF ou CNPJ de acordo com o que o usuário selecionar no select.

Preciso criar mais um campo no banco de dados do WP para enviar esses dados (CPF ou CNPJ), qual seria a tabela mais recomendada para estar enviado essa informação?

Esse campo eu terei que criar diretamente no banco de dados ou da para utilizar um custom fields do WP?

Grato.

Comment: Seria interessante voce dar uma estudada sobre Custom Post Types e custom fields. No link você consegue ter uma noção http://vinteum.com/wordpress-campos-personalizados-custom-fields/

Comment: Eu utilizo dessa forma para manter a integridade do Wordpress